# Is it possible to load a database directly from HDFS into spark as a DataFrame?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I have my MongoDB and Spark running on Zeppelin, both sharing the same HDFS. The MongoDB produces a .wt database stored in the same HDFS.

I want to load the database collection produced by that MongoDB from the HDFS into a Spark DataFrame.

Is it possible to load the database directly from HDFS into spark as a DataFrame? Or do I need to use a MongoDB Spark connector?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203325/how-to-query-when-connecting-mongodb-with-apache-spark may be a good starting point.

Comment: What's the on-disk format? It's definitely possible with sufficient coding and sufficient memory, of course.

Comment: DataFrame df = sqlContext.read.format("com.stratio.datasource.mongodb").options(options).load

Comment: @thebluephantom can you further elaborate your code please

Comment: I just saw it and hence it is just a comment, look at https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-connect-Spark-with-MongoDB

Comment: @Marcin this is running on centos6 (x86_64)

Comment: He didn't ask the OS, he asked the format of the data. You need to find if Spark can read whatever that `wt` format file is.

Comment: JosephAdam As per @cricket_007, the os is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend to read or modify the internal [WiredTiger Storage Engine's](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/) `*.wt` files. Firstly, these internal files are subject to change without notifications (not a public facing API), also any unintended modifications to these files may cause the database to be in an invalid/corrupt state.

You can utilise [MongoDB Spark Connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/) to load data from MongoDB to Spark. This connector is designed, developed and optimised for the purpose of read/write data between MongoDB and Apache Spark. For example, by accessing data via the database the client may utilise the [database indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) to optimise read operations.

See also:

- [GitHub demo: Docker for MongoDB, Apache Spark and Apache Zeppelin](https://github.com/rozza/docker-mongodb-spark-zeppelin-demo)
- [GitHub demo: Docker for MongoDB and Apache Spark](https://github.com/sindbach/mongodb-spark-docker)